# How to uncheck a checkbox onclick a button in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have few checkboxes,whose Value is coming from loop,Here my requirement is only onload all checkbox will be checked by default,but on click clear button all checkbox should be unchecked,Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let child of nestedjson; let i = index"><input type="checkbox" checked>{{child.name}}</li>
<div><button (click)="clear()" type="submit">clear</button></div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import Speech from 'speak-tts';
import { RxSpeechRecognitionService, resultList, } from '@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

  providers: [ RxSpeechRecognitionService ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {  
    showit:any;
    nestedjson:any;
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,public service: RxSpeechRecognitionService) {
     }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.nestedjson = [
        { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
        { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
        { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
      ];
      this.showit = true;

} 

clear(){

}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the modified solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crcoq3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<li *ngFor="let child of nestedjson; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="child.checked">
  {{child.name}}
</li>

<div><button (click)="clear()" type="submit">clear</button></div>
```

.ts:

```
nestedjson = [
    { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"], checked: true },
    { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"], checked: true },
    { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"], checked: true }
  ];

  clear() {
    this.nestedjson.forEach(child => {
      child.checked = false
    })
  }
```

If you cannot change the json, do this:

.ts

```
checkedItems = this.nestedjson.map(x => ({ name: x.name, checked: true }));
```

.html

```
<li *ngFor="let child of nestedjson; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkedItems[i].checked">
  {{child.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,We cannot change json here,we cannot add 'checked: true' inside json

Comment: This is the ‘correct’ approach though. Why can’t you add the checked keys? They don’t have to exist in the ‘original’ json, but you can make a copy maybe?

Comment: Check the modified demo